# Django date YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, django, timedelta

I get date in format(YYYY-MM-DD)

Then I want to add timedelta

```
    mydate + timedelta(days=1)
```

and I get error

```
    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mydate` is a string. Try doing this:

```
from datetime import datetime
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(mydate, "%Y-%m-%d")

new_date = parsed_date + timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Data sent by the client will be sent as a Unicode and you have to parse it on server side

```
datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If it's part of a form, the data should be reformatted automatically when cleaned (though you might need to configure the field to accept the format you expect).

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your string date to python `datetime`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> dt_str = "2013/10/11"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y/%m/%d")
>>> new_dt = dt + timedelta(days=1)
>>> print new_dt
 datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 12, 0, 0)
```

If you now want to get the date as string:

```
>>> print new_dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
 '2013/10/12'
```